# Hive Custom Lazy Thrift SerDe is no longer lazy on CDH4

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

I am working with a SerDe that processes Thrift object entries in a variety of ways based upon the base dataset.  It is essentially a glorified Hive Struct that processes the base set of data at runtime rather than store the results in a table.  Recently, I've upgraded the cluster from Hive 0.7.1 to Hive 0.10.0 (with CDH3 -> CDH4.3.0) and the SerDe no longer lazily processes the data but instead appears to be processing every single field defined.

I've dug through Hive's code, and looked through how our data is being deserialized in order to understand how it determines what fields it wants to process, but unfortunately it seems like it is processing all of the columns simply because our ObjectInspector returns all the fields of our custom object, and I can't seem to figure out how to control what fields are being processed.

What parts of Hive can I manipulate to change what fields are being processed?  Is there a way I can detect what fields are being used in a query in order to disable functions in my object's internal state?

Edit:  I realized that it'd be useful to include a stack trace to show where a particular function to process the data is being called due to it being an inspected field.

I've replaced the custom class names with descriptive names for their roles instead.

```
2013-10-08 17:02:45,198 INFO CustomStructFunction: Stack trace: java.lang.Throwable
    at CustomStructFunction.init(CustomStructFunction.java:490)
    at CustomStructFunctionBase.process(CustomStructFunctionBase.java:27)
    at CustomStructObject.callImplementor(CustomStructObject.java:332)
    at CustomStructField.callImplementor(CustomStructField.java:161)
    at CustomStructField.getValue(CustomStructField.java:131)
    at CustomStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(CustomStructObjectInspector.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorConverters$StructConverter.convert(ObjectInspectorConverters.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:141)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:417)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that our custom object was returning a new ObjectInspector every time we asked to get it.  This was causing Hive to think that the input format for the custom struct was separate from the exported format, which triggered Hive to convert the data into a base struct object, which essentially meant processing every single field.

Instead of returning a new ObjectInspector every time in our base custom struct definition, I instead leave it to the extending class to define a static ObjectInspector that starts out as null.  The parent class then calls the method "getInnerObjectInspector", and if it gets null, it sets it using the similar set method with a new instance.